# An old member removed the link to my site on the question should I re-add it?

Tags: support

Here is my question: [What are the reasons RPM falls this much?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127180/what-are-the-reasons-rpm-falls-this-much)

And here is the edit: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/127180/revisions

> Removed link to site. Please note that links to sites are generally frowned upon by the community since they're often associated with spam and self-promotion.

I get this reason. But when it comes to the question I want the answerer to check out the site. RPM values might drop because of placement, because I'm using zoom on the ads, because a whole bunch of other things that can be understood once a person looks at the site. So the reason why I want it back there is because I believe I will get better answer.

But if it is still not approved, I understand.

Comment: Questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. As a reference site for future visitors, if users need to view your site then it's likely not a good fit here, since websites can change, become unavailable, etc... As explained in the edit comments: `links to sites are generally frowned upon by the community since they're often associated with spam and self-promotion`, so we typically remove them.

Comment: In short, questions here need to be generic, self-contained, and applicable to others, so unless we ask for links in comments, please do not add them. This was also the [second time](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/119554/revisions) a moderator removed a link to your site from your question, so that should probably have indicated before that links to individual sites aren't condoned here.